# running multiple SQLs one being select and others are inserts using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am new in PHP. I am trying to run these sqls all at once. I need to run the
sql with SELECT in it in order to obtain a value from that result and insert that value to the two remaining sqls. How can I achieve what I want?

The three sqls to be executed:

```
$sql = "SELECT (unitPrice) FROM product WHERE productID = '".$pid."';";
$sql .= "INSERT INTO order (orderID) VALUES ('".$rnd_id."');";
$sql .= "INSERT INTO order_details (orderID,orderType,orderDate,orderTime,quantity,orderPrice,discount,discountPrice,employeeID) VALUES ('".$rnd_id."','".$type."','".$date."','".$time."','".$quantity."','".$oprice."','".$dis."','".$dprice."','".$eid."')";
```

EDIT:

So far this is what i have done. The first sql is running but the other two is not.

P.S. Everything else that is needed to be inserted has value except the ones who need the unitPrice in order to have value.

```
$sql = "SELECT (unitPrice) FROM product WHERE productID = '".$pid."'";
        $sql1 = "INSERT INTO order (orderID) VALUES ('".$rnd_id."');";
        $sql1 .= "INSERT INTO order_details (orderID,orderType,orderDate,orderTime,quantity,orderPrice,discount,discountPrice,employeeID) VALUES ('".$rnd_id."','".$type."','".$date."','".$time."','".$quantity."','".$oprice."','".$dis."','".$dprice."','".$eid."')";

        if($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                $price = $row['unitPrice'];
                $oprice = (double)$price * (double)$quantity;
            }   
        } else{
            echo "Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
        }

        $dprice = $oprice - $oprice * $dis;

        //Free result set
        mysqli_free_result($result);

        if(mysqli_multi_query($link, $sql1)){
            do {
                /* store first result set */
                if ($result = mysqli_store_result($link)) {     
                    mysqli_free_result($result);
                }
            } while (mysqli_next_result($link));
                //Records created successfully. Redirect to landing page
                header("location: index5.php");
                exit(); 
        } else{
            echo "Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
        }
```

EDIT:

The tables in which is needed to have oprice and dprice have a value is this:

```
PRODUCT - name of table

Columns
productID - PK
productName
categoryID
unitPrice
unitsInStock
discontinued
```

I am trying to gather the unitprice where the entered value of productID is. This worked but the insertion part (the other two sqls) did not execute. Please help.

Comment: What do you mean by *all at once*? It would be better practice, and easier to debug, if you run them one at a time, and check for errors before proceeding to the next statement. Also, instead of building the SQL statements and embedding the values, use prepared statements and bind the variables to the statement. That will avoid SQL Injection problems.

Comment: how can i run the statements one by one?

Comment: I haven't seen the unitPrice attribute in any of your insert queries. can you point it out?

Comment: CREATE TABLE `product` (
 `productID` varchar(7) NOT NULL,
 `productName` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
 `categoryID` varchar(7) NOT NULL,
 `unitPrice` double NOT NULL,
 `unitsInStock` int(5) NOT NULL,
 `discontinued` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`productID`),
 KEY `categoryID` (`categoryID`),
 CONSTRAINT `product_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`categoryID`) REFERENCES `category` (`categoryId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

productId is the primary key of the product table shown above. It is needed to access the unitPrice.

Comment: But in question you mention that first query has executed fine, you are getting issue in insert queries. can you clearify where you are facing the issue?

Comment: Yes, the first query executed and I had gathered what I needed to be inserted. The problem is that if what I had done is right to execute the other two. It seems that what I did is not working.

Comment: @KeimaKun dont post your table structure in the comments. Edit your question and add the missing information in it

Comment: already edited. Thank you for the guidance. Just new here.